# Python: relocation error

Tags: python, glibc

**Problem:**

Suddenly python is giving following error in my raspberry pi on which *raspbian* *jessie* is running.

‍‍‍
`me@mypi:~$ python
python: relocation error: python: symbol (some not printable characters), version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file  libc.so.6 with link time reference`

**python and glibc version:**

`python version 2.7.9
libc6 version 2.19`

**What I have done already:**

I have tried to purge python package and reinstall but it seems apt-get isn't functional anymore for the above problem. After downloading the packages when it tries to install same error is thrown, then dpkg fails to install. For the same reason I failed to install libc6 too.

I have already searched through web for the solution. But didn't find exact same problem or any workable solution. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "suddenly"? Was it working before? With the same python/libc versions?

Comment: Yes! Didn't upgrade / change any packages before the problem.

Comment: This is for ubuntu, but it can give you some clues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6